# Match the macOS version number only by major and minor version number

Tags: regex, bash, macos, if-statement, glob

Trying to deal with a result of 10.12.3 - how would I code this when the OS has an optional third numeric value to consider?  And, of course, this changes often, so I don't want to look for extended updates. Just the main OS 10.12, 10.11, 10.10, etc.

```
   if [ "$osv" = "10.12" ]; 
    then
        appi="Applications:App Store.app:Contents:Resources:AppIcon.icns"
    elif [ "$osv" = "10.11" ]; 
    then
        appi="Applications:App Store.app:Contents:Resources:appStore.icns"
    else
        exit
    fi
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could take your variable `$osv`, keep only the first two fields (assuming that fields are delimited with `.`), and use the result in the `if/else` statement(s):

```
v=$(echo "$osv" | awk -F. 'BEGIN{OFS="."}{print $1,$2}')
```

so if `$osv` is `10.12.3`, `v` will be `10.12`. In case `$osv` is merely `10.12`, `v` will be equal to this value as well.

Comment: @JamesDean `awk` takes the content of `$osv` as its input, splits it into fields (delimiter specified with `-F`) and then prints only the first two joined with the output field separator specified with `OFS`. This output is then saved into the variable `v` using the `$(...)` syntax...

Comment: @JamesDean or you could combine this approach with `sw_vers` and obtain the major.minor version directly as `v=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F. 'BEGIN{OFS="."}{print $1,$2}')`

Comment: If the version number is already in a shell variable, this is a bit heavy-handed, but if you're calling `sw_vers -productVersion` anyway, it's a viable approach, though `sw_vers -productVersion | cut -d. -f1-2` is simpler.
(As a potentially interesting aside: `awk`'s `-F` option normally expects a _regex_, but passing `.` is an exception that is treated _literally_ - perhaps because splitting by any character doesn't make sense (you'd only ever get empty fields).)

Answer (score 2):

Use `=~`, Bash's *regex-matching* operator, inside `[[ ... ]]`:

```
if [[ $osv =~ ^10\.12(\.?|$) ]]; # ...
```

This matches both `10.12` and `10.12.3`, for instance.

With some duplication you can also use glob-style *patterns* in a `case` statement, which may be the best choice in your case:

```
osv=$(sw_vers -productVersion) # yields, e.g., '10.12' or '10.12.3'
case $osv in
  10.12|10.12.*)
    appi="Applications:App Store.app:Contents:Resources:AppIcon.icns"
    ;;
  10.11|10.11.*)
    appi="Applications:App Store.app:Contents:Resources:appStore.icns"
    ;;
  *)
    exit
esac
```

Note:

- [*Patterns*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) (as also used in globbing) are:

  - conceptually simpler, but much less powerful than *regexes* (regular expressions).
  - can be used for string matching on the RHS of `==` inside `[[ ... ]]` as well as in `case` statements (see above; inside `case`, their use is even POSIX-compliant).
- By contrast, *regexes* can only be used for string matching inside `[[ ... ]]` with the `=~` operator.